# Can not restore minimized/switched full-screen applications/games

Tags: windows-7, windows, fullscreen

Recently I re-installed a fresh copy of **Windows 7** with all available **updates** downloaded for both **Windows** and **Drivers** and with no problems at all.

Everything was good but when last night I started **Steam** in full-screen mode then started a video game and switched to desktop, then I couldn't switch back to either both of them from the taskbar or even with `Alt-Tab`.

I had figured only two ways to switch back; the first by `Bring to Front` from the `task manager` (Doesn't work with all) and by `Restore` by right-clicking the taskbar icon preview.

What could be causing this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you rebooted since the problem occurred?  Some games change the display driver settings and they may not have changed back (esp if the game is one that does not like to be minimized).

Comment: Of course, I did. Even tried to restore to a previous point. And no, i don't think it's my driver as I tried and re-installed it.

Answer (score 0):

Different games behave differently in Full-Screen mode. If you can run the game in a Window or a Full-Screen-Window you should not have this issue. If you must run in Full-Screen then do not ALT-TAB out if you know there is an issue. The way the graphics sub-system behaves with Full-Screen (non-Windowed) games is completely different to a Windowed app.

Are you saying it use to work correctly before your re-install and now does not (you are not clear on this matter).

Comment: It used to work before and after i re-installed. This just happened last night, and actually no, i know what you mean but it's quite the same in windowed-mode as well (talking about games) and as i said i can switch back but not with `alt-tab` or just by `clicking` on the taskbar as i used to.

Comment: Kevin, welcome.  Super User compiles questions and answers for reference so it is important that answers be just answers.  Asking for clarifying information should be done with comments on the question, which it shouldn't take you long to accumulate enough rep for.  However, you can comment on your own posts now.  To ask the questioner a question that they will see as a comment in their little inbox at the top, create a comment on your answer and start it with @Hossam.